# How to link Trac with a remote git repository? (2 seperate servers)

Tags: git, trac, git-post-receive

I have 2 servers

- Server 1: Contains my central git repos
  the second
- Server 2: Contains my edgewell Trac enviroment

I am trying to get trac to update tickets based on git commit messages.

I know that there is a post-receive hook but that will only work on the server 1

How do I tell server 2 to run the trac-admin changeset added cmd?

Also if I created a clone of the git repo on server 2 then I am to use git pull cmds which in turn would call the post-merge hook but this doesn't seem to get called with the same stdin parameters that the post-receive  hook has.

Is there a way of setting up server 1 to run an ssh cmd or send a data payload to a web cgi script on server 2 that performs a pull request on the cloned repo and proceeds to perform the trac-admin changeset added cmd?

Answer (score 1):

[trac-github](https://github.com/trac-hacks/trac-github/) has a request handler for a GitHub webhook that does a `git update` (`git.remote('update', '--prune')`) and then runs *changeset added* (`rm.notify('changeset_added', reponame, added)`). You could write a small plugin that response to a request and does the same, and send the request from a `post-receive` hook using `curl`.

However, it might be simpler to [push to the mirror repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3583114/121694) from the main repository and have the mirror run the `post-receive` hook to sync the changeset to Trac.

Comment: I like the second option. I looked at the first option but got too confused on what was required to get the hook working.  Any examples would great.